# Formatting an external link with optional query params

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on an Angular app that needs to link to a fixed (external) route with some query params that are set on the Angular page itself. I'd like to provide some sort of nice data-binding in my Angular HTML, like:

```html
<a href="http://www.api.com/query?param={{value}}&flag={{check}}">Link</a>
```

However, all my query parameters are optional. This is easily handled within an Angular app itself, using something like

```js
$location.path('/query').search({param: value, flag: check});
```

Is there any way I can get the benefits of this declarative style when I just want to format a text link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realised that the ideal mechanism for this is probably a [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters). It leverages automatic data-binding and is really simple to use. The HTML becomes:

```html
<a ng-href="http://www.api.com/endpoint{{params | query}}">Link</a>
```

And the filter code:

```js
myApp.filter('query', function() {
  return function(opts) {
    var params = [];

    for(var opt in opts) {
      if(opts.hasOwnProperty(opt)) {
        if(opts[opt] !== "" && opts[opt] !== undefined) {
          params.push(opt + "=" + opts[opt]);
        }
      }
    }

    return params.length
      ? "?" + params.join("&")
      : "";
  };
});
```

And [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fX2JK/1/). This filter handles `undefined` properties and empty strings... perfect for my own use-case but I realise it might not be for everyone. Anyway, the filter code itself is pretty simple to modify (and you could easily replace it with [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) if that suits you).

EDIT: I've since realised that AngularJS sets models bound to an empty input to `null`, so in my actual code I'm checking against `null` in the filter.

Comment: You can just check for: `if(opts[opt]) {...}`

Comment: @PavelNikolov what if `opts[opt] === false`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ngHref` attribute like this:

```
<a ng-href="http://www.api.com/query?param={{value}}&flag={{check}}"></a>
```

Here is a link to the documentation: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngHref

Comment: Oh! That's a good idea, thanks. But from the documentation I see no mention of what might happen if `value` or `check` (or both) is undefined. In the `$location` code, they will not be included in the URL.

Comment: If you don't want them to be included in the URL then have a `queryString` variable and populate it in the controller. Then just include this variable in the URL `http://example.com/query?{{ queryString }}`

Comment: By the way if you use an `undefined` variable, then your url will look like this `"http://www.api.com/query?param=&flag="` which might work out of the box - the parameters on the other end will be empty strings.

Comment: I wanted to find a solution that means I don't have to bother with manual data-binding (using a string, I would have to `$watch` the components and regenerate the string myself).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary operator in the expression enclosed by the double curlys.  For instance: `{{value ? 'param='+value : ''}}` will result in "param={{value}}" if param exists and is true otherwise it will result in "".

So you can do the following:

```
<a href="http://www.api.com/query?{{value ? 'param='+value : ''}}{{check ? '&flag='+check+'' : ''}}"></a>
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xa9c/2/)

Comment: That's what I was afraid of! I guess it's not so bad, and having `?` on the end of the URL even with no parameters isn't going to cause any havoc.

Comment: True, or you could write a test that checks if any parameter exists to use for the "?". The tradeoff is your html starts getting complicated with logic

Comment: @DanielBuckmaster I would still populate the whole query string in the controller and then have an url like this `example.com/query?{{ query_string }}` - avoid having any calculations in the databound expressions. If the expression is in the controller it will be executed only once!

Comment: If you go the controller route- which does have it's separation of concerns advantages- I'd be tempted to use a function so that your parameters are updated along with value, check, etc... (assuming those values change during execution)  So in @PavelNikolov's example I might do:  example.com/query?{{ query_string(value,check) }}

Comment: @KayakDave usually I avoid having functions in the bound expressions - it's not always possible but if it's a large grid with links etc I would have just a single value or using some sort of `bind once` mechanism (there are multiple available out there). The whole point is that for every data-bound expression Angular registers a watcher which evaluates the expression. If the expression is a variable then it's very fast. If there are any operations or function calls it tends to get slower. Of course if you just have a single data-bound expression in the view it doesn't matter.

Comment: @KayakDave do function calls automatically get reevaluated when their arguments change in the controller? I'm tempted to try this route. Or would I have to `$watch` the parameters?

Comment: @PavelNikolov in this case I'm only binding to a single URL so performance isn't critical. I appreciate the discussion though.

Comment: Function calls are executed each time the expression is evaluated.  Thus, @PavelNikolov valid concern.  They can become expensive, but they give you the data binding you're looking for.  And I think it's easy to prematurely optimize in JS as the engines are moving in a direction where clean code is sometimes also the fastest code.