# Equivalent to ui-router's "ui-sref" in ngRoute?

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-href

Is there any kind of equivalent to [ui-router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/)'s [ui-sref](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref)?

As of now **all** my `ng-href`'s are hard-coded string literals, ex;

```
<a ng-href="#/users/{{user.id}}/{{user.fullname}}"></a>
```

which makes me shiver whenever I see it.

Are there any built-in functionality in `ngRoute` that handles this, or do I have to make my own service? Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is shiver worthy.

According to the ng-href documentation, they also expect you to hard code all params as strings. Ui-router supports the object param paradigm out of the box with the [ui-sref directive](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref). (Here's an [article](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angular-routing-using-ui-router) for getting started with ui-router since you asked if there are alternatives).

If you do not want to switch to ui-router but you are willing to use query string params, something like this may work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21082131/3914443. It's an angular filter which simply turns your object into a query string for the next view/controller route.

Comment: `ngRoute` is way too integrated in my app at the moment to revert it :(. I actually started with `ui-router` but ditched it because they didn't support optional parameters. I'm gonna try and make a provider which'll act as a funnel when setting up app routes. This way I can store & access data about a route from anywhere within my app, and even make a method that "generates" urls.. somehow. I'll see how it goes.